# SmtpFailedRecipientException and SmtpFailedRecipientsException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, smtpclient

I'm struggling to differentiate these two exceptions especially based on their properties and usage:

- They both define a `FailedRecipient` property for a single email address
- If you catch `SmtpFailedRecipientException` this masks `SmtpFailedRecipientsException`

Logically, I would expect the plural version to take priority - the server was unable to send your email to any of the recipients - over the server being unable to send to a single specific recipient.

But then what if you send to 8 recipients and two of them fail - now what exception do you get?

What should a properly handled call to `SmtpClient.Send()` look like in terms of catching `SmtpFailedRecipientException`, `SmtpFailedRecipientsException` and `SmtpException`?

Comment: Sad to see this didn't get a response - I'm in exactly the same position

Answer (score 5):

[SmtpFailedRecipientsException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientsexception?view=netframework-4.5.2) is a sub-class of [SmtpFailedRecipientException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientexception?view=netframework-4.5.2). Also `SmtpFailedRecipientException` is a sub-class of [SmtpException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpexception?view=netframework-4.5.2).

> But then what if you send to 8 recipients and two of them fail - now what exception do you get?

The exception that you will get is an `SmtpFailedRecipientsException`.

> What should a properly handled call to SmtpClient.Send() look like in
>   terms of catching SmtpFailedRecipientException,
>   SmtpFailedRecipientsException and SmtpException?

```
try {

    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);    
}
catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException recipientsException)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Failed recipients: {string.Join(", ", recipientsException.InnerExceptions.Select(fr => fr.FailedRecipient))}");

    // your code here
}
catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException recipientException)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Failed recipient: {recipientException.FailedRecipient}");

    // your code here
}
catch (SmtpException smtpException)
{
    Console.WriteLine(smtpException.Message);

    // your code here
}
```